TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype((numpy.record, [('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])) to dtype('float64')
I tried to bundle data using Pandas and draw it with maplotlib, but an error occurred.
How do I solve this error? TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype((numpy.record, [('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])) to dtype('float64')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

a = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2},
    {'x': 0, 'y': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'y': 0},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 1},
    
    {'x': 3, 'y': 2},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 1},
    {'x': 3, 'y': 0},
    {'x': 4, 'y': 1},
]

b = pd.DataFrame(a)
c = np.array(b[['x', 'y']].to_records(index=False))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.add_collection(PolyCollection(c))
plt.show()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\test.py", line 80, in <module>
    ax.add_collection(PolyCollection(c))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "..\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1200, in __init__
    self.set_verts(verts, closed)
  File "..\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1241, in set_verts
    self._paths.append(mpath.Path._create_closed(xy))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "..\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 199, in _create_closed
    v = _to_unmasked_float_array(vertices)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "..\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 1398, in _to_unmasked_float_array
    return np.asarray(x, float)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype((numpy.record, [('x', '<i8'), ('y', '<i8')])) to dtype('float64').


Is there a specific reason you're using a records array?

Wouldn't providing a NumPy array be drawn faster than a list? @jared

My question is why you are specifically using a records array instead of a standard numpy array. The error is a consequence of that unusual choice.

I heard that this is the fastest way to convert from Pandas to NumPy arrays. Do you have any other recommendations? @jared

Yeah, my answer shows how you can convert the pandas array to a regular numpy array.

is to_numpy faster than to_records??? @jared

I'm not sure how they compare (you can test it), but it doesn't really matter which is faster if matplotlib PolyCollection doesn't work with records arrays.

It's not clear why you're using a records array here. This can be done by directly converting the pandas DataFrame to a numpy array using the .to_numpy() method. b.to_numpy() returns an array with shape (8,2).
You also need to be aware that PolyCollections expects a list of 2D lists/arrays containing the vertices with shape (M,2). So, after converting the DataFrame to an array we then have to put it into a list.
Lastly, adding a collection doesn't trigger a rescale of the axes limits, so I added a call to ax.autoscale_view().
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

plt.close("all")

a = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2},
    {'x': 0, 'y': 1},
    {'x': 1, 'y': 0},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 1},
    {'x': 3, 'y': 2},
    {'x': 2, 'y': 1},
    {'x': 3, 'y': 0},
    {'x': 4, 'y': 1},
]

b = pd.DataFrame(a)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(PolyCollection([b.to_numpy()]))  # put the array into a list
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()

Result:

